# how to use ref in stateless functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new for react, there is my code

It's printing `undefined` in console, how to make it work?

```
const Example = () => {
  let node;
  return (
    <div>
      <p ref={el => (node = el)}>hello world!</p>
        {console.log(node)}
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Please do your research for `How to's`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because the block you log the node in it is different from function block if you run below code :

```
const Example = () => {
  let node;
  return (
    <div>
      <p
        ref={el => {
          node = el;
          console.log(node);
        }}
      >
        hello world!
      </p>
      {console.log(node)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

you will see the `node` ref as `<p>hello world!</p>`in your console . if you want to use ref your way is correct you just need to set it to the proper variable with good scope for example use  `window.node`  test
link is: https://codesandbox.io/s/kxj92vojmo.
 the best solution to your problem is using state manager as MobX to share ref and states between your view and viewModel